# How to use a vertical layout stepper within R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to create a nice vertical stepper (like [that](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview)) within my Shiny app, for which some of the steps would be displaying R/shiny widget/reactive values (such as graphs, tables, etc.). Is there any specific widget that allows that?

It could looks like something like this within ui.R:

```
ShinyStepper(vertical = TRUE, 
             linear = TRUE,
             theme = "default",
             step1.title = "Title of first step",
             step1.body = {
                 h3("This is a reactive barplot"),
                 plotOutput(outputId = "reactive_barplot")
             },
             step2.title = ...
             )
```

Comment: Not exactly that, but maybe you are interested in [shinyglide](https://juba.github.io/shinyglide/).